# adding dates to the line chart in matlab

Tags: matlab

let   us suppose  we have following date

```
Year    Number
2003    632
2004    559
2005    567
2006    540
2007    628
2008    517
```

and i want to  plot is as a line chart, for this i used plot command, but about date i know that there exist two function  datenum and  datetick, for the  last one  i know that there is such  format'

```
datetick(‘x’, ‘dd mmm yy’, ‘keeplimits’, ‘keepticks’)
```

please tell me exactly how can i  add  year  to the x  axis using these two command? i have tried following command

```
>> plot(datenum(Year),number)
>> datetick('x','yyyy','keeplimits','keepticks');
```

but x  axis  is not in correct  date format. thanks in advance

Comment: thank you sir, one question  when i  am typing  following command  pie(pound,snack)  where pound is numbers and snack are  categorical names,  result on pie chart is given without percentages, how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have year number (not month and date), so simply [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) as:

```
plot(Year, Number); 
set(gca,'XTick',Year);  %if necessary
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2):

Since you only have years, the best `datenum` overload I can see for obtaining correct dates is the following:

> DateNumber = datenum(Y,M,D) returns the serial date numbers for
>   corresponding elements of the Y, M, and D (year, month, day) arrays.
>   The arrays must be of the same size (or any can be a scalar). You also
>   can specify the input arguments as a date vector, [Y,M,D].

You can pass it dummy value for month and day values (`1`, for example) since what you want to be shown are just years:

```
C = {
  2003    632
  2004    559
  2005    567
  2006    540
  2007    628
  2008    517
};

T = cell2table(C,'VariableNames',{'Year' 'Number'});

plot(datenum(T.Year,1,1),T.Number);
datetick('x','yyyy','keeplimits','keepticks');
```

Alternatively, you can just use your year values for defining the x-axis tick, as follows:

```
C = {
  2003    632
  2004    559
  2005    567
  2006    540
  2007    628
  2008    517
};

T = cell2table(C,'VariableNames',{'Year' 'Number'});

plot(T.Year,T.Number);
set(gca,'XTick',T.Year);
```